Transitivity of the gauge action for quantum Yang-Mills theories
The basic definition of principal bundles involves free and transitive action of the group $G$.
And, it is well-known that classical Yang-Mills are modelled on principal bundles, where $G$ corresponds to the gauge group.
Now, I am curious if

the action of the gauge group $G$ remains somehow transitive even after quantization.

At least, according to my understanding, the Gribov ambiguity implies that gauge action is NOT free at the quantum level.
However, I haven't been able to find a reference dealing with the transitivity issue yet.
Could anyone please provide any information?

What is the Gribov ambiguity supposed to have to do with transitivity of the gauge action? When you ask about the theory "after quantization", the action of the gauge group on which space are you talking about?

@ACuriousMind I wrote that Gribov ambiguity implies the group action not being "free". I didn't mean that it has to do with transitivity. I will re-edit the post.

@ACuriousMind The space on which the gauge group act must be the space of all (gauge-noninvariant) states, with certain states like the ghosts having negative norms. However, I admit that I don't have a complete picture yet; I am just guessing vaguely in analogy to classical theories.

The space of all "gauge-noninvariant states" is not well-defined (e.g. ad hoc non-Abelian extensions of Gupta-Bleuler construct a different intermediate space than the full formal BRST procedure), the only thing that is is the final space of gauge-invariant states, so I don't see how this question would be well defined. Also, since we quotient the gauge action out of any such intermediate space to obtain the physical space of gauge-invariant states, of course the action can't be transitive on that in general - since in that case, the physical state space would be a single point

Note, for comparison, that the action of $G$ is free and transitive on the fiber of the classical principal bundle, but it is not transitive on the classical phase space (by the same argument, since the space of classical gauge-invariant states is the symplectic reduction by the group action on the phase space). Perhaps you confused the action on the fiber with the action on the classical states when coming up with this question?

@ACuriousMind Oh, yes it looks so. Could you tell me exactly how the phase space is defined for classical gauge theories (or principal bundles)? I guess it must be the classical analogue of all possible states (including ghosts) in the quantum theories.

@ACuriousMind I appreciate any useful reference so that I can take a close look myself. I don't have detailed knowledge on geometric formulation of gauge theories, so it will help a lot for me.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
